# In sql without insert values in table, how i can see column of table

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

```
SQL> create table justlike(customerid varchar(19),first_name varchar(40),last_name varchar(100),Address varchar(50),city varchar(30),pincode varchar(10),state varchar(20));
```

Comment: `select * from justlike` should return the column headers, even if there are no rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```sql
   desc <table_name>;
```

This will print the description of your table columns

in your case:

```sql
   desc justlike;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the table definition, in case you are using Oracle, by running below query -

SELECT  * FROM USER_TAB_COLS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'JUSTLIKE';

OR you can write a select on table itself -

SELECT * FROM JUSTLIKE;

Comment: thanks for help sir, but what I ask that is different from your answer.

Comment: "what I ask that is different from your answer".  Then you should clarify your question.  This answer is exactly in line with all other answers and comments.